A short story where a space pilot has a device that sends the ship back in time just before losing a space battle. He is duplicated by accident
Fairly sure I read the story in a mammoth Sci-Fi collection around 15 years ago. The character is fighting another ship, triggers the time shift defense, and inadvertently creates a duplicate of himself. The duplicates are named 'first name' then blue or red depending on which version they are. One version ends up doing hard labour on a mining colony and is shamed. Can't remember the fate of the other.

"A device that sends the ship back in time just before losing a space battle" reminds me of the Omega 13 (Galaxy Quest).

This is very reminiscent of Stephen Baxter's novel Exultant which has a pilot named Pirius, who is duplicated and referred to as Pirius Red and Pirius Blue.  The Wikipedia article does not mention a short story version, but I'll  continue to look.
From the article:

Commissary Nilis of the Office of Technological Archival and Control,
part of the Commission for Historical Truth, defends both the older
Pirius (whom he calls "Pirius Blue") and the younger one ("Pirius
Red") but loses the trial. Pirius Blue is sent to a penal unit at the
front as a foot soldier, and Pirius Red is remanded to the custody of
Commissary Nilis, who has plans for the fruits of Pirius Blue's
battlefield victory. Using the Xeelee fighter and the innovative
tactics that saved Pirius Blue, he starts to plan an unheard of
assault on the Xeelee's primary stronghold at Chandra itself.


This is it, thank you. Looks like its a book not a short story. I think I read an introduction or sample or a bit of the book. It has haunted me, I would try to remember what he was called, for some reason I was convinced his name was Johnny.

Please click the checkmark, too, when you have the chance - thanks

Ah, new to the site, is that for reputation? I've ordered the trilogy today. Thanks again

It marks the question as solved - and give me some reputation too :)  Welcome to the site!
